# defining derivative function through sympy

Tags: math, diff, sympy

diff works with polynomials but diff(sin(x),x) gives out the error message.
When I removed "from math import *" from the code, diff(sin(x),x) worked. Why is it? What of "math" crashes with symbolic differentiation of trig function?

Comment: make sure that the arguments of Sympy functions such as `diff` are Sympy objects. In particular, `sin` should be the *Sympy version* of sin, i.e., the correct usage is `sympy.diff(sympy.sin(x))`. To avoid such issues, it is good practice not to import modules using `import *`

Comment: Thanks! yet to understand the difference between sympy version of sin and math version of sin. but knowing that there is difference helps to understand this crash.

Answer (score 3):

SymPy functions only work with SymPy functions.

The functions in the `math` module are numeric functions. They only know how to work with numeric arguments (floats or ints). If you give them a symbolic expression like `x` they won't know what to do. This is because only SymPy functions know how to stay unevaluated.

It is recommend to not use `import *` unless you are working interactively, and even then, do it from at most one module. SymPy functions and expressions do not mix with numeric functions from modules like `math` or `numpy`.

Instead, you can run

```
import sympy as sym
```

and use `sym.sin` and so on.

Also, in general, it should not be necessary to use the `math` module at all when using SymPy, as everything implemented in the `math` module is also in implemented in SymPy.